# How to deploy AWS Lambda that will be accessible only via public API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have configured public API Gateway and AWS Lambda (AWS Lambda is not in a VPC) which are integrated. I can call API Gateway and it redirects the requests to AWS Lambda and it works fine.

Recently I spotted that in cloud formation in outputs sections for the lambda stack is available key `ApiURL` with URL like this https://[magic-number].execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com/Prod/.

I pasted this link to a web browser and I was surprised that I got response "Welcome to running ASP.NET Core on AWS Lambda".

Does it mean that my lambda can be called directly from Internet?
My intention was to hide the lambda and use API GW with authorization using AWS Cognito.

How I can make the lambda private and make sure that it will be accessible only from public API GW? Do I have to deploy this lambda to private subnet in a VPC or it does not have to be a VPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by following next steps:

1. Go to your Lambda function in AWS Console.
2. Open **Configuration** tab and click **Function URL**.
3. Click **Edit** button.
4. For `Auth type` choose `AWS_IAM`.
5. Click **Save** button.

Now your Lambda is not available via it's URL, but API Gateway can access it: [Using the AWS_IAM auth type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html#urls-auth-iam).

Or just:

1. Go to your Lambda function in AWS Console.
2. Open **Configuration** tab and click **Function URL**.
3. Click **Delete** button and pass through confirmation.

Now any internet access is removed and only way to access the lambda function is via API Gateway!

If you want to explore more, please take a look at **VPC**, also can give your the results: [Internet and service access for VPC-connected functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help#vpc-internet)

Now lambda is hidden and you can configure AWS Cognito to use with API Gateway.

Answer (score -1):

By default, a Lambda function is not accessible from the public internet.

The URL that you see in your stack is actually the URL of the API Gateway. When you go to that URL in your browser, if you get the response from the Lambda function, that means that you have a GET method mapped to your Lambda function without any authentication method set in your API GW.

If you want to secure your Lambda function so it cannot be called without auth, steps will depend on the type of the API Gateway that you created (REST or HTTP), but in general, it's:

- Add Authorizer to your API GW (it can be Lambda or Cognito)
- Go to `Resources` section of your API GW, choose a proper method that you use to invoke the Lambda function
- Edit
- Add Authorizer that you created in step 1
- Re-deploy API GW

Comment: It is possible to configure Function URL when creating lambda, so it can be accessible from the public internet.

Comment: @SerhiiH it's possible to configure it, but by default it's not configured. Also, OP didn't mention that they have Function URL set, but API Gateway URL actually (the URL that he provided is for API Gateway stage, not Function URL)